# Adding group headers at run time : Expandable List View android

Tags: android, runtime, expandablelistview

I am using android expandablelistview. Initially it has 5 group headers and child items in it. At run time based on the selection, i want to add one more header/group to the expListView.

I have tried updating the values and called BaseExpandableListAdapter method notifyDataSetChanged. But nothing happens at run time.

```
static HashMap<String,List<String>> mapSubCat;

And mapSubCat is filled with initial data.

exQuestLV = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

expQuesListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,arrCategories,mapSubCat);
exQuestLV.setAdapter(expQuesListAdapter);


//Adding data to mapSubCat based on selection: 

mapSubCat.put("Sport Name", arrSubSports);

expQuesListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
expQuesListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```